# Unity, How to get specific controller input with multiple controller(joysticks)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, controller, gamepad

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1I64.png)

I found to get how many controllers connected.

But how do we know each different controller's input?

Example:
Assumption: 1st Player - Keybord and Mouse, 2nd Player - 1_Xbox Controller, 3rd Player - 2_Xbox Controller
What I want: Get 2nd Player and 3rd Player controller's input using for statement

```
for(int i =0; i<3; ++i)
{
    Inputdata data;
    if(i == 0)
        data = GetKeyboardMouseInput();
    else
        data = GetControllerInput(i);
}
```

like this way

Get Inputdata with each different controller's input?

- I am not using New Input System

Comment: For axis inputs, set Joy Num to "Joystick 1", "Joystick 2", etc (instead of "Get Motion from all Joysticks"). For button inputs, use the joystick-specific button events ("joystick 1 button 0" instead of "joystick button 0").